# Concatenating layers with diffrent shapes

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have 2 layers with the following shapes.

Layer 1: LSTM

```
K.int_shape(x)

(None, None, 500)
```

Layer 2 : Conv2D -> Flatten -> Reshape

```
K.int_shape(y)

(None, 1, 2352)
```

I need to concatenate them, but I get the following error.

> ValueError: A 'Concatenate' layer requires inputs with matching shapes
>   except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, None, 500),
>   (None, 1, 2352)]

I'm using Keras v2.1.4

Comment: You can't. `Concatenate` requires all the dimension to be the same except for the dimension concatenated on. But you have a second dimension that doesn't match

Comment: Yeah it is not possible.

Comment: I wanted to Reshape Layer 2  to (None, None, 2352) but i couldn't. is that possible ?

Comment: Its variable sized, so it won't work all the time, the None's in your shape are also a problem.